# Regex not returning any matches for UPS tracking numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `trackingNumber="1Z96Y3W80340983689"` 
for which I want to test a regex pattern against;
with the regular expression: `"/1Z\\?\[0-9A-Z]\\{3}\\?\[0-9A-Z]\\{3}\\?\[0-9A-Z]\\{2}\\?\[0-9A-Z]\\{4}\\?[0-9A-Z]{3}\\?\[0-9A-Z]|\[\dT]\\d\\d\\d\\?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\?\\d\\d\\d/i"`
in java

But I'm not getting any matches for my regex.

Comment: You need at least to remove regex delimiters `/..../i`.

Comment: 1Z\\?\[0-9A-Z]\\{3}\\?\[0-9A-Z]\\{3}\\?\[0-9A-Z]\\{2}\\?\[0-9A-Z]\\{4}\\?[0-9A-Z]{3}\\?\[0-9A-Z]|\[\dT]\\d\\d\\d\\?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\?\\d\\d\\d\                                                 still getting some error.

Comment: "My Regex isn't working. Need the correct expression" the correct expression for what? you havent said how `trackingNumber` needs to be validated. what are the rules? where are your test cases?

Comment: give us a couple more examples of what your trackingNumber could look like, right now the question is very vague

Comment: IF Tracking starts with ‘1Z’
                Tracking = tracking.left(18)
                                IF tracking.matches(/1Z ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{2} ?[0-9A-Z]{4} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]|[\dT]\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d/i) {
                                                Carrier = ‘UPS’
                                }

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches UPS tracking numbers:

```
/\b(1Z ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{2} ?[0-9A-Z]{4} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]|[\dT]\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d)\b/i
```

Here is a list of regular expressions for some other known tracking number patterns: http://gummydev.com/regex/

Comment: Thank you @Andrea Corbellini 2rep for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

```
1Z?(?:[0-9A-Z]{3})?(?:[0-9A-Z]{3})?(?:[0-9A-Z]{2})?(?:[0-9A-Z]{4})?(?:[0-9A-Z]{3})?[0-9A-Z]|[\\dT]\\d\\d\\d?\\d\\d\\d\\d?\\d\\d\\d
```

You probably need this.Do no escape special charaters.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/6

Comment: can you please let me know what does (?:[0-9A-Z]{3})? exactly mean.I need some help to understand this.

Comment: @sougatadas it make the whole `[0-9A-Z]{3}` part optional and non captruing

Comment: can you elaborate pls.I am unable to understand.

Comment: @sougatadas it mean that group inside `()` is optional.It can be there or not....